How to open flutter based app using gesture(like swipe up four fingures to open app)
I'm making an app for blind it is completed almost only thing remaining is that for easyness of blinds I want my app will open when user swipes up or down four fingers. can anyone help me that how  I can add this feature to my app. My app is flutter based that's why I am facing difficulty in solving this issue.
I tried some packages but these packages  are not working for this feature.

Please mention packages which you tried, in this question.
